# Error adding Service Reference in VS2010 containing webHttp and wsHttp

Tags: wcf, service, reference

I'm creating a webservice with a wsHttp and JSON endpoint. The config below is hosted in a website project and works fine except when I try to create a service reference WITHIN the website. The  endpoint behaviour seem to cause the error:

> "Extension Error 'webHttp' cannot be added to this element. Verify the exception is registered in the extension collection at system.servicemode/extensions/behaviorExtensions"

It doesn't throw an error in svcUtil.exe. It seems VS specific but I'd like to get the bottom of it.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JSON">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="HelloWorldBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="HelloWorldBehavior" name="HelloWorld">
          <endpoint address="/json" behaviorConfiguration="JSON"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IHelloWorld" >
            </endpoint>
          <endpoint name="wcf"  address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
          contract="IHelloWorld" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you tried to browse to the service using IE? If so were there any errors?

Comment: What is the framework you are using? Also has the project been migrated from VS2008 to Vs2010. If so try to delete the service reference and add it again.

Comment: No it's a fresh project and I've deleted it and added several times

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether it would solve your problem or not, but I think I should share my experience on a similar problem here.

I was getting an almost similar error:

> Extension element 'webHttp' cannot be added to this element. Verify that the
>   extension is registered in the extension collection at
>   system.servicemodel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.

[image: error message]

I tried a lot of things to fix this thing but couldn't do it. Then I found this suggestion on a similar problem from [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/9beac730-8744-45d4-94db-391550d8cd8f) page:

> check your client (ASP.NET MVC) config and comment the WCF endpoint
>   behavior which uses `<enableWebScript />`. Then add your service
>   reference and uncomment the behavior. Same procedure has to be done if
>   you want to update existing script reference. I guess it is a bug and
>   should be reported to Microsoft Connect.

Mine wasn't ASP.NET MVC, but I tried the suggestion by commenting out

```
<behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
```

this portion from my app.config and could add the service reference then!! Then after adding the reference I just uncommented that portion again.

I can't explain it. It just worked for me and that's why I am sharing. Thanks.

Comment: Nice graphic. I kept trying to close your popup.